# Sending data stored on a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller and service

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('Spliptter', Spliptter) // Controller
    .service('SplitService', SplitService); //Service

    function Spliptter($scope, SplitService){
        var result = SplitService.phoeNoSplit($scope.phoneNumber.number); //Phone Data

    $scope.area: result['area'];
    $scope.country: result['country'];
    }

    function SplitService() {
      this.phoeNoSplit = function(phoneNumber) {
         var area = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3); //Info that I want to send
         var country = phoneNumber.substring(3, 10);  //Parse

         return {
             'area': area,
             'country': country
          }
     }
}
```

Also I have a form where I use to send the area code and the country code.

```
angular //Controller of the form that i'm using to send the area and country code
.module('myApp')
.controller('formController', formController); // Form controller
   function formController($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
       $scope.SendFormController = function () {
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:myURL.com,
                data : {
                        ciaPhone: $scope.TokenResponse.datos.ciaPhone,
                        phoneCountry: $scope.country,
                        phoneArea: $scope.area
                        }
                }, // form fields
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }//
            })
            .success(function ( data, status, headers) {
                $rootScope.datosPersonales = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        }; //
 }
```

But, I dont know whats the problem. I'm new in angular.

Comment: Hola Patricio. Si te equivocaste del sitio donde colocar la pregunta, por favor reporta tu pregunta y solicita una migración. Un moderador se encargará de migrar la pregunta al sitio en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Please read angular docs first so that you will get better understanding how controller and service works.

Here issue is you are trying to access the scope of Spliptter controller into formController controller which will never possible.
If you have to use that scope values in formController then you will have to initialise those scope values in formController itself.

### Refer below code:

### formController

```
 angular //Controller of the form that i'm using to send the area and country code
.module('myApp')
.controller('formController', formController); // Form controller
   function formController($scope, $http, $rootScope, SplitService) {
      var result = SplitService.phoeNoSplit($scope.phoneNumber.number); 

      $scope.area: result['area'];
      $scope.country: result['country']; 

       $scope.SendFormController = function () {
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:myURL.com,
                data : {
                        ciaPhone: $scope.TokenResponse.datos.ciaPhone,  // am not sure from where you are getting it
                        phoneCountry: $scope.country,
                        phoneArea: $scope.area
                        }
                }, // form fields
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }//
            })
            .success(function ( data, status, headers) {
                $rootScope.datosPersonales = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        }; //
 }
```